# is it possible to define document values based on other values in mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `limit` and `count` on a model schema. I would like to have a boolean `reachedLimit` become true once those two values are equal. Is there a way to calculate this automatically in the model or do I need to do it  manually?

I tried the below code and it always returns `true`. Even if it returned false as expected, I think it would assign `reachedLimit` a default value on creation, and then never reassign the value. What is the best way to dynamically check for equality on the model?

```
const invitationSchema = new Schema({
    limit: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    reachedLimit: { type: Boolean, default: {
        $eq: ['$limit', '$count'],
    } },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding `reachedLimit` as a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) in your schema:

```
const invitationSchema = new Schema({
    limit: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    count: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
invitationSchema.virtual('reachedLimit').get(function() {
    return this.limit === this.count;
});
```

As the name implies, this won't actually add the field to your *saved* documents, but is generated as an additional property when querying documents.

Comment: thank you! I would use `this.count >= this.limit`, but otherwise this is the perfect solution.